# Configure Doxygen to Generate Separate documentation for separate root folders

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have multiple applications in one folder. 
I want to generate separate doxygen documentation for every top folder.

```
root-folder
  -- test-app
  -- myapp_1
  -- myapp_2
```

I want to generate doxygen documentation for all three in one run but to place results in three different folders.

I tried to set `CREATE_SUBDIRS`, but this has a different purpose.

I would like to have

```
html
  - test-app-html
  - myapp1-html
  - myapp2-html
```

Comment: Having multiple applications in one folder is not the best choice, you are probably better off by having a library (and include) directory with the common code and the different main programs in different subdirectories. This was a bit off topic. Doxygen cannot build documentation to multiple directories in one go so you have to do a number of builds and in the doxygen configuration files for the different builds have different settings regarding the files to be used (INPUT tag) and the output directory (OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, in your case html, and HTML_OUTPUT myapp1-html, myapp2-html).

Comment: OK 'Doxygen cannot build documentation to multiple directories in one go'   is enough.  To make it clear, it is not possible for this.

Comment: It is possible to have documentation generated as you said in one go by one doxygen call, but when wrapping the different doxygen calls in a script  you can do it in "one go".

Comment: I am currently doing something similar for multiple libraries of a single project using a Makefile (if you use `make`, of course). In my case, it is the Makefile's job to make it appear "one go".